# Parse fixed width content

Tags: parsing, antlr4, fixed-width

Is it possible to parse fixed width content?

I sketched the following, but it does not compile:

```
grammar FixedWidth;

content: name age birthday;

name: character[10, false];
age: integer[2, false];
birthday: date['yyyy-MM-dd', true];
salary: float[9, 2, true];

character[int n, boolean required] locals [int i=1]:
    ({$required && $i == 1}? NONBLANKCHAR {!$required && $i == 1}? CHAR {$i < $n}? CHAR {$i++;});

integer[int n, boolean required] locals [int i=1]: ({$i <= $n}? INT {$required}? | SPACE {$i++;});

float[int n, int decimals, boolean required] locals [int i=1]: ({$i < $n}? INT {$i == $n - $decimals - 1}? '.' {$i++;});

date[String dateFormat, boolean required] locals [int i=1;int n = $dateFormat.length();String mask = $dateFormat.replace('y', $INT).replace('M', $INT).replace('d', $INT)]: ($mask {!$required}? | String.format("%" + $n + "s", "")) ;

NONBLANKCHAR: ~[SPACE] ;

CHAR: [.] ;

INT: [0-9] ;

SPACE: ' ' ;
```

Forgive me in case of any dumb error above. I am newbie to g4.

Comment: are you asking if you can parse lines of whatever language but restrict the length/width of each line?

Comment: Questions like this (fix-my-code-for-me) are not well received here at SO. Reword your question and ask specific details instead.

Comment: This code doesn't look very much like ANTLR code. You should first make yourself familiar with the correct ANTLR4 syntax.